# What is Alphabetic keyboard control in uwp app?

Tags: xaml, user-controls, keyboard, uwp

Is there a control available for something like this [Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoyeD.png) in xaml or is this a custom control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, none of the available input scopes looks like this. Must be a custom control that looks like a keyboard.

Comment: can you please suggest from where to start?